# Using pdf function in R to save plots AND data frames

Tags: r, pdf, grob

I recently discovered the function `pdf()` in R.
I know it can only be used to save plots but I wanna use it to save texts and data frames too. So I am trying to cheat the function by using the `grid` package and `grob` objects but I cannot figure out how to do it.
Could somebody input a code showing how to convert a data.frame to something that can be saved by the `pdf()` function, or any other methods that would provide the same result ? I would appreciate.

Comment: there are at least a few packages that let you output data to pdf tables, like `xtable`

Comment: Thanks a lot this seeems to convert it to a nice LateX object !!!
But how can I use it to display with the pdf function ?
This code does not return anything :   `pdf("report.pdf",width=7,height=7)`     
`p<-xtable(dataframe)`    
`dev.off()`

Comment: do you need to specifically use the `pdf` function?  or are you just trying to output data to pdf?

Comment: I would rather use pdf function but if you have something as simple (not the markdown) and that can also work with plots that could interest me a great deal !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer somewhere else in stack :
[writing data frame to pdf table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14321127/writing-data-frame-to-pdf-table)
[Adding text to a grid.table plot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11774703/adding-text-to-a-grid-table-plot)
Sorry for not having looked harder before !

Answer (score 0):

If you're willing to move away from the `pdf` function, you could use a combination of `knitr` to produce the table in `LaTeX` format, and `pandoc` and `rmarkdown` to render it as a pdf. Here's a quick example:

````
sink("trial.Rmd")
```{r, echo = FALSE}
exampleDF <- data.frame(a = 1:5, b = letters[1:5])
knitr::kable(exampleDF)
```
sink()

rmarkdown::render("trial.Rmd", "pdf_document")
````

Note that this solution, as noted above, depends on having `pandoc` installed. But it also depends on having `LaTeX` installed. Hope it's helpful.

**EDIT:** Sorry, just noticed you mentioned you'd rather not use markdown, but the above should work if you're willing to go that way.